# With Travis CI testing older R versions, what is the best way to handle package ‘***’ is not available (for R version ***)?

Tags: r, travis-ci, cran

I have an R package I wish to support back to R 3.4.4
With my most recent commit the older R builds error with this:

```
package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
```

And I imagine more packages may flag up in future.

On a local machine I would simply install a compatible older version of XML from cran. I have a small R script to do this.

How do I ask Travis CI to install compatible versions of packages in my DESCRIPTION file?

.travis.yml file

```yaml
language: R
cache: packages
sudo: false
dist: bionic
cran: http://cran.rstudio.com

branches:
  only:
  - /.*/
  
r:
  - 3.4
  - 3.6
  - release
  - devel
```

Comment: Not sure but maybe add a line to install the archive(only know how to do this with GH actions although I've never tried it). Perhaps add this line to the `script` part of your yaml file?

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem and it's also with the XML package. Any luck figuring out the solution?

Comment: Yeah I've not found a way to fix this yet :( Still waiting for a hero in the comments section

Comment: I fudged a solution and forced it to install an earlier version of XML. Seems to do the trick. Added this to the travis yml:

before_install:
- wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/XML/XML_3.99-0.3.tar.gz
- R CMD INSTALL XML_3.99-0.3.tar.gz
- rm XML_3.99-0.3.tar.gz

Comment: Thanks and this would work sure.
I was looking for a data-driven process ideally. Not sure I have the effort of adding multiple hard-coded install flags like this in the coming years.

Comment: Agreed, this is far from ideal. Seems like a problem that really should have a better solution.